# Neatbeans: Editing PHP and double clicking a variable name

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I have recently made the switch from Dreamweaver (10+ years) to Netbeans and am loving it. The only issue I'm having is I'm use to being able to double click a PHP variable name and the code editor auto selecting the variable name but NOT including the leading $.

So if you double click $variableName only variableName gets highlighted.  In NetBeans if you double click $variableName , you automatically select the entire variable name and the $.

I understand it's a small issue, but I double click variable names and drop them into bindParams about a hundred times a day and it's driving me nuts to have to always remove the $ after pasting.

Using Netbeans 7.4

Comment: i've checked it but the only thing i could find is that the double click behaviour can't be changed in netbeans.

Comment: Ok, thanks for looking CosLu

Comment: +1 it drives me crazy as well also for the '-' as in button-big. it's treated differently in HTML, JS, CSS, PHP some consider it as a part of the var name some consider it as a separator.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds rather like a macro for repetitive task. If you have `$categoryName` in your clipboard, you can turn

```
$data->bindParam(|); // | is where cursor is
```

into

```
$data->bindParam(':categoryName', $categoryName);
```

with this simple macro: (tools->options->Editor->macros tab->new, name it, paste code, set shourtcut)

```
"':" paste-from-clipboard caret-forward ", " paste-from-clipboard match-brace caret-forward caret-forward delete-next caret-end-line
```

Comment: Good idea, but not really what I'm looking for.  Guess in the end I just really would like to be able to double click a php variable and not have it select the $.   I try and use the same variable names across multiple languages (php, mySQL, html and Jquery) and they all work nicely together, cept that all php variables start with the $.